# Unknown check digit algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a database table whith thousands of identities with an associated check digit.

```
0        | 0
00       | 0
0010     | 3
001001   | 4
001002   | 1
00100201 | 4
00100202 | 1
001003   | 8
001004   | 5
001094   | 2
00109401 | 5
00109402 | 2
00109403 | 9
0020     | 6
002001   | 1
00200101 | 4
00200102 | 1
002003   | 5
00200301 | 2
00200380 | 9
002072   | 9
059501   | 0
00207201 | 2
002080   | 8
00208007 | 3
00208017 | 6
00208057 | 8
00208065 | 7
00208070 | 5
00208075 | 0
```

The identity length can vary from 1 to 8. My problem is that I need to implement the algorithm but I can't find which is the one. I also don't know how the right padded spaces enters the algorithm, if at all. The developers are inaccessible. Any ideas?

### Edit

For anyone interested based on the correct @Henning answer this is my Postgresql implementation:

```
create or replace function dv_conta (conta char(8))
returns integer as $f$
    select right(sum(d * p)::text, 1)::int
    from unnest(
        regexp_split_to_array(lpad(conta,8,'0'),'')::int[],
        array[3,7,9,3,7,9,3,7]
    ) a (d,p)
$f$ language sql immutable;
```

Comment: Can you provide more context to help understand how variable length can be handled ?

Comment: @Yves I edited the question but I really don't know much.

Comment: You didn't add any context, did you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the values you quote are consistent with the following procedure:

- Pad with zeroes on the left until the number has 8 digits, $d_7d_6d_5d_4d_3d_2d_1d_0$.
- Compute
  $$ w_7d_7+w_6d_6+9d_5+w_4d_4+7d_3+9d_2+3d_1+7d_0 $$
  where $w_7$, $w_6$ and $w_4$ are some weights that the data you show don't allow me to determine -- except that $w_4$ needs to be odd.
- The check digit is the last digit of the sum.

Based on the weights that *can* be derived, one might guess that the full list of eight weights is $3,7,9,3,7,9,3,7$.

Comment: Right on the spot, including the weigths. What is the name of the algorithm, if publicly known?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: I don't think it has a fancy name -- I would just call it a "modulus-10" check digit. I tried googling for this particular weight sequence, but nothing useful came up.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: Ah, I got it. If we invert the weights, we can check the _final_ code by multiplying the digits of the code _including_ check digits, by the weights 7,3,1,7,3,1,7,3,1 -- and the sum must the be 0 modulo 10. There are multiple references to "7-3-1 check digit" in Google; it seems to be widely used in the financial industry.